# Logical operators relevance in XQuery

Tags: xquery, logical-operators, relevance

what operation is more relevant in XQuery: AND or OR?

For example: (a and b or c) is equal to 1 o 2?

1. (a and b) or c
2. a and (b or c)

Cheers,
Deborah

Comment: I dont know about xquery but **[THIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Programming_languages)** says it should be `(a and b) or c`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that by "is more relevant" you mean what other people would phrase as "binds more tightly" or "has higher precedence".  In XQuery, `a and b or c` is parsed as `(a and b) or c`, not as `a and (b or c)`.

This may be seen in productions 46 and 47 of [the XQuery grammar](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#id-grammar):

> [46] OrExpr ::= AndExpr ( "or" AndExpr )*
>
> [47] AndExpr ::= ComparisonExpr ( "and" ComparisonExpr )*

It may also be exhibited in an XQuery engine by evaluating the expression `false() and true() or true()`.  That this is a result of operator precedence and not of left-to-right evaluation can be seen by re-ordering the expression and evaluating `true() or true() and false()`.